# How do you make popcorn with "indian corn"

Tags: microwave, popcorn

I bought a couple ears of this corn at the farmers market and the woman at the stand said to throw it in the microwave.  Does anybody know how long it should be in the microwave for?

Comment: What is "indian corn" to you? What country are you from?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: "Indian Corn" could be referring to corn that looks like this: http://www.stormeffects.com/indian_corn.htm whereas plain "corn" usually refers to stuff like this: http://www.hessdesignworks.com/Corn.html Yes, they're closely related plants, but for making popcorn the microwave time might vary (such as if Indian Corn has a different water content than sweet corn, or other varieties).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner and TFD - good points indeed. I shall delete my comment.

Comment: the corn in this pic http://www.stormeffects.com/indian_corn.htm is not best for pop corn, u can just boil it or fry it over charcoal and eat.

Answer (score 3):

When popcorn pops, it makes a distinctive popping sound (unsurprisingly). I would microwave the ear of corn until the pops come about ten seconds apart - at this point, you're well into the tail of the normal distribution which describes how long it takes each kernel to pop. If the corn doesn't pop after about two minutes, it probably won't pop at all.

Comment: Two minutes?!? You would have a microwave full of charcoal! I wait for 2-3 seconds apart and then pull it.

Comment: @Sobachatina: 2 minutes might not be so bad on a medium setting, depending on the microwave. My parent's old microwave, 1.5 minutes on Med-High was ok for popcorn, IIRC.

Comment: @Sobachatina - I agree, 2 minutes is a long time here. It is more than enough time to hear the first pop, and if no pops occur in this time, the cob is "broken" - more than 2 minutes might well start a fire, 2 minutes may not...

Answer (score -2):

First get a decent size iron [karai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karahi) (rounded heavy pan).Now heat up the pan with low fire continously.Get some clear sand on it,heat up the sand.Now pour the corns and stir softly until it gets popcorn.After that get the popcorns

Comment: Could you update your answer with a source for buying clear sand?  I don't know where I'd get any kind of sand that I'd want to cook on!  Searching for "clear sand" turns up a lot of pool cleaning supplies and veterinary supplies.

Comment: Why would you want sand in your popcorn? Sounds like a great way to do dental damage.